# How to delete an AWS CloudWatch Metric Filter if the Log Group no longer exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I had a Lambda function named "Foo".

When it ran, it logged to a CloudWatch Log Group named "/aws/lambda/Foo".

I created a Metric Filter on the Log Group named "Bar".

I accidentally deleted the Log Group before deleting the Metric Filter. So now I have an orphaned Metric Filter named "Bar".

How do I delete "Bar"?

Comment: Did you try cli's `delete-metric-filter`?

Comment: I did. It errors saying the log group doesn't exist.

Answer (score -1):

If you have deleted the cloudwatch log group, it will delete the associated metric filter as well.

Comment: This does not associate the existing metric, it creates a new one with the same name.

Comment: If you have deleted the Cloudwatch log group, then it would have deleted the associated metric filter as well.

Comment: That is not correct. That is the whole purpose of asking this question. The Metric Filter still exists and I have no way of deleting it.